# Bash (Shell) - copy only specific files to new folder

Tags: shell, command-line

I have some .csv files which I want to copy in a backup folder.

I find them with the following command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv"
./data1.csv
./data2.csv
./data3.csv
```

It is possible to pipe the result of my find command to the copy command? In reality there are ~200 files. Listing them manually is no option.

I thought of something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" | cp ./backup/
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You're looking for the [xargs](https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/) command.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Linux Shell". Please read the description of the "shell" tag which you applied, it contains further info.

Comment: `find . -type f -name "*.csv" | xargs -i cp {} ./backup/` => This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a for loop. For fn in (your find conditions);do cp $fn destination; done